# Cloud Service (Extended Support) Deploy using DevOps Release Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cloud-services

Can any one know how to deploy Cloud Service Extended support using DevOps Release Pipeline. Thank you

I tried to deploy cloud service (extended support) using the old cloud service release pipeline and encounter an error saying "ConflictError: The specified DNS name is already taken."

Answer (score 1):

Different with classic cloud service, we use [ARM template deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-resource-manager-template-deployment-v3?view=azure-pipelines) to create or update the CSES deployment for CICD process. You can follow the doc [How to use Azure DevOps to publish cloud service extended support](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/how-to-use-azure-devops-to-publish-cloud-service-extended/ba-p/3675180) for the detail steps. It's yaml pipeline, but you can use same way in classic release.

[image]

Regarding the error `ConflictError: The specified DNS name is already taken`, it's typically occurs when you’re trying to create an Azure Cloud Service with a DNS name (such as a custom domain) that is already in use by another resource(such as another cloud service, web app, or custom domain). You could follow below options for a check:

1. Choose a unique DNS name that is not currently in use.
2. Ensure that you’ve completely removed any `previous` deployments associated with the same DNS name. Also, check for any DNS records in your DNS provider.

Comment: should i also create those json files?

Comment: Yes, for Cloud Service Extended support, you need to create the json files for `ARM template deployment`  task.

Comment: this json files is added on the source code right?

Comment: Yes, you can add the json files to the source code, here is the [sample code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cloud-services-extended-support/tree/main/101-cses-multirole-rdp) for your reference.  Also the doc about [ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services-extended-support/generate-template-portal).

Comment: @SocA, may i know if you have generated the ARM template and used the task in pipeline? On the doc shared, there's a `Download a template for automation` link. thanks.